# Sequelize transaction doesn't work after some time without restarting PM2

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, sequelize.js, pm2

All API using Sequelize transactions stops working after some time in PM2 as a process manager where are other simple queries works fine. It shows `pending` in XHR request. But after restarting the PM2 it works fine but after few hours it stops. I am facing this problem with only those api's that are using Sequelize transactions. What could be the issue?

here is my configuration
Server - UBUNTU 20.04
PM2 - 5.2.2
express - ~4.16.1
sequelize - ^6.7.0

Comment: Check if you have not closed transactions before restarting on DB side.

Comment: Sequelize is a well known library which probably is not the reason in your case. Please provied your database and sequalize initialization options and database access code. In most cases this is due to missing express response on an error case or database transactions locking each other or of course unclosed transactions...